# Delete PFObject without having to download first?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Is there a way to delete an object on parse.com without having to download it first? I know you can get a count of objects without having to download them, I was wondering if it's possible to delete them in a similar way?

Comment: How do you know what it is that you want to delete?

Comment: There are a number of objects on the server, that I know I won't need, and I want to delete them, but don't particularly want the game to download them all just to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cloud code function that contains the logic to find and delete the items which are no longer needed, then simply trigger the function when required.

Otherwise, if you know the object id you can use the rest interface or, you should be able to, use `objectWithoutDataWithClassName:objectId:` to create the local representation of the object without any network calls and then use `deleteAllInBackground:` to delete the object(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could delete it through the REST API if you have the object URL.

By the way: A PFObject is only the representation of an Parse Object on iOS, so if you have an PFObject it's generated from a Parse object. So deleting through REST API is without any PFObject directly deleting Object in Parse Cloud, not deleting an PFObject.